# Basic idea behind java.util.arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

So I've been using arrays in java for a while now, and just recently discovered

java.util.Arrays

I was just wondering if my understanding of the concept is ok?

So here is what I came up with

When using the standard array class for basic work, there is no need to import arrays
An import statement of "java.util.Arrays" is only necessary when we want to use the static methods that are available to the Array class.

Comment: Arrays is a library class that contain fuctions to manipulatearrays. Example, sort, copy etc...

Comment: Yes, generally you import classes which you want to use in your code. You can create instance of such class or use their static members.

Answer (score 3):

Yup, you got it right.

`java.util.Arrays` is a class with a bunch of helper methods - if you don't intended on using them, you don't need to import the class.

Comment: Same with ```Objects``` and ```Collections```.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly. You can manipulate and use arrays without importing java.util.Arrays.

The `java.util.Arrays` contains various static methods for manipulating your arrays - `search`, `fill`, `sort`, etc. The point is that you don't have to write implement these common utility functions - just use the methods in the class.